# Loop fragment with guard conditions in UMLET

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, tool-uml, umlet

I am using UMLET to design the UML Sequence diagram for my system, i don't use the "all in one" option but the simple one dragging and editing the diagram components, so far so good, but i need to create an **alt fragment** with 2 or 3 guard conditions, i can't findd examples or documentation about it, the fragment component in the program doesn't show how to achieve my goal, could someone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create alt fragment with the `interaction frame` thingy in the palette.

Then in the diagram itself you can populate it with something like

```
alt
--
[x>0]


--
[x=0]


--
[x<0]
```

[image]

### Note:

I would highly advise you against using this palette. Once you start making changes to it, it is a nightmare to manage as everything starts to misbehave — e.g. if you wanted to increase the space for `[x=0]` part, then you would add `<enter>` in the Properites window, however the messages and rest of the diagram will not move and you have to adjust it manually.

Not to mention that creating it manually this way is more time consuming.

So if you want to create sequence diagrams, you should either use the all-in-one palette, or other tool, such as PlantUML which has much nicer syntax (and looks better):  http://plantuml.com/sequence.html

Comment: I would use `halign=left`.